# In React, a <button> with icon does not trigger function

Tags: reactjs

I use `reactstrap`. I have this kind of `<button>` with an `icon` inside :

```js
{this.props.mode === "update" 
  ? 
     <Button 
        className="btn btn-danger btn-sm" 
        onClick={() => this.deleteQuestion()}
     >
       <i className="fa fa-trash"></i>  
     </Button> 
  : null 
}
```

If I **click on the `icon`**, the function in not triggered.
If I **click outside the `icon`** (but inside the button), the function is triggered.

What is this mystery? I am a beginner in React and react-strap.

Comment: Did you try putting onClick function on the icon itself?

Comment: You can also try removing pointer events from the icon. 
`<i className="fa fa-trash" style={{pointerEvents: 'none'}}></i>  `

Comment: This is the first time I have seen something weird like this. Agree with Haber's solution, but I think it is a bit waste of effort. I recommend you should give `Ant Design` or `Material-UI` a try for larger community support. Have a look at [this Antd Button](https://ant.design/components/button/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it behaves this way is because icon captures click before it is propagated to the button. The easiest way to fix this is to add the following in your css

```
.btn i.fa{
  pointer-events: 'none';
}
```

it will fix it for all the buttons in your project

Comment: Hi Max. thank for the answer. I think it is the best one in my context. Even if I discovered that there is a lot of other available answers. I tried and it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is a concept called `event capturing and event bubbling` in JavaScript. Take a look at [Event Capturing and Event Bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing). This concept helps you overcome the problem that you're facing currently.Take a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing). You can add the same function onClick to the `icon` too. This will help you as well!!.. There are so many design templates available you can try those too. For eg. There's [Ant Design](https://ant.design/). Hope it helps!!.. **Happy Coding!!**